# Insert All Into query not executing against hsql db even after setting dialect Oracle

Tags: spring, oracle, hsqldb

I have a query which inserts data from a list into Oracle DB table. The query format is

```
Insert All 
Into Table_A (Column_A, Column_B) Values (Value_A1, Value_B1) 
Into Table_A (Column_A, Column_B) Values (Value_A2, Value_B2) 
select * from dual;
```

This query works fine when I run it against the Oracle DB.

But when I execute the same query against HSQLDB(embedded DB in Spring) as part of tests, it throws an exception saying the SQL Grammar is incorrect.

I am using Oracle syntax for the hsql by specifying `SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX ORA TRUE;`

hsql version - ***2.3.2***

Can any one throw help why I am facing this issue, even after specifying the Oracle dialect?

Part of exception stack that I get is pasted here -

```
----------


DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] (SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java281) - Unable to translate SQLException with Error code '-5581', will now try the fallback translator
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: ALL required: INTO : line: 3
### SQL: Insert All         INTO TABLE_A (column_a, column_b) VALUES (?,?)         INTO TABLE_A (column_a, column_b, TABLE_A_active) VALUES (?,?)         select * from dual
### Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: ALL required: INTO : line: 3
; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: ALL required: INTO : line: 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that `SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX ORA TRUE` enabled complete support for Oracle SQL syntax. According to [the docs](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html)

> This property, when set true, enables support for non-standard types. It also enables DUAL, ROWNUM, NEXTVAL and CURRVAL syntax and and also allow compatibility with some other aspects of this dialect.

So it would appear to give limited support for those Oracle constructs, but not the full SQL syntax addions that you're locking for.

If you want to run SQL across multiple databases, you really need an abstraction layer of some kind, such as Hibernate or QueryDSL.